# Has someone connected a PostgreSQL DB hosted in GCloud with Microsoft SSMS?

Tags: postgresql, powerbi, ssms, gcloud

I have a question, I do not know how to solve it yet. Perhaps someone here has faced a similar issue.
We have a PostgreSQL DB hosted on Gcloud. We usually use a cloud proxy to connect with the database. It usually works very well!! In a nutshell the proxy connect a port from local host, to the actual DB host.

However this time, we want to connect it with Microsoft SSMS. We have not find an option where we can connect Microsoft SSMS with a DB running locally (this means connecting to a database on a port in local host).

The ultimate goal is to connect the database with Power BI. So if someone know how to connect a PostgreSQL DB hosted in GCloud to power BI that would also be very helpful!!

We have followed this tutorial:
https://www.anibalum.com.ar/2020/06/creating-linked-server-with-postgres.html

However we get the following error:

> The linked server has been created but failed a connection test. Do you want to keep the linked server?
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
> Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "PAPERFLOWDB".
> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "PAPERFLOWDB" returned message "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid connection string attribute".
> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "PAPERFLOWDB" returned message "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7303)

We are using Microsoft SSMS v18.9.1

Comment: SSMS is for SQL Server (and some other SQL Server based Microsoft Products, such as Azure SQL Database), not PostgreSQL.

Comment: Though your error suggests you are creating a linked server; so you aren't connecting SSMS to your PostgreSQL server, but are connecting SSMS to a SQL Server instance, and then that has a linked server for a PostgreSQL server. Is that correct? SSMS <> SQL Server, so if you *do* mean SQL Server (not SSMS), correct your question appropriately,

Comment: Can you provide confirmation for above comment so that we can help you with your issue?